# Crop image to fill parent having height that is relative to width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill div container with an image by cropping it instead of stretching. I need the image to be centered even if it's in landscape or portrait orientation.

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 133px;
  /* padding-bottom: calc(33.3% - 2px); */
  height: 133px;
  background: violet;
}

img {
  /* margin-top: 100%; */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.landscape {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  max-height: 100%;
}

.portrait {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.square {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="landscape" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>   
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="portrait" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/dd/59/4e/dd594e241abf617abed2b7d586c19ef9--female-portrait-model-portraits.jpg?b=t">
    </div>   
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="square" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
    </div>    
</div>
```

I need it to be applied to containers having height that is relative to width instead of pixels. But it won't work on [landscape images](https://jsfiddle.net/adacnum/ez91xnLb/3/). So far it's working on portrait images. Please help, thank you.

[image: percentage dimensions]

Comment: I haven't found a solution to solve this with CSS only so I have no choice but to use JS to identify if the image is in landscape/portrait/square which adds a class for each type.

Answer (score 1):

remove `min-height: 100%` of `.landscape`. `img` already has `min-height: 100%`

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 133px;
  /* padding-bottom: calc(33.3% - 2px); */
  height: 133px;
  background: violet;
}

img {
  /* margin-top: 100%; */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.landscape {
  /* max-width: 100%; 
   max-height: 100%;*/
}

.portrait {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.square {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="landscape" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>   
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="portrait" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/dd/59/4e/dd594e241abf617abed2b7d586c19ef9--female-portrait-model-portraits.jpg?b=t">
    </div>   
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="square" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but only the landscape image's right and left part should be cropped. Just like the portrait image's top and bottom parts were cropped.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace

```
 .landscape{
    max-height:100%;
}
```

with

```
 .landscape{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

also add margin top and bottom like below:

```
img{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
```

}

Comment: Thank you but only the landscape image's right and left part should be cropped. Just like the portrait image's top and bottom parts were cropped.

Comment: add    margin-top: auto  & margin-bottom: auto;  inside img tag css code.

Answer (score 0):

For `.landscape` use `min-height: 100%;`.

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1px;
  width: calc(33.3% - 2px);
  padding-bottom: calc(33.3% - 2px);
  height: 0;
  background: violet;
}

img {
  margin-top: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.landscape {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.portrait {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.square {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="landscape" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>   
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="portrait" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/dd/59/4e/dd594e241abf617abed2b7d586c19ef9--female-portrait-model-portraits.jpg?b=t">
    </div>   
    <div class="img-container">
        <img class="square" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but only the landscape image's right and left part should be cropped. Just like the portrait image's top and bottom parts were cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from tag img  `min-width: 100%;  min-height: 100%;` && add attribute `width=100%`

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 133px;
  height: 133px;
  background: violet;
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.landscape {
  /* max-width: 100%; 
   max-height: 100%;*/
}

.portrait {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.square {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="landscape" width="100%" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="portrait" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/dd/59/4e/dd594e241abf617abed2b7d586c19ef9--female-portrait-model-portraits.jpg?b=t">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="square" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```